# Idea of multiple stars in Vedas

Tags: vedas, astrology

Sun is a star nearer to us.

I heard that Vedas do mention that there are multiple stars in the universe. But don't know the name of Veda and other details.

Which Veda mentions that there are multiple number of stars (suns) in this universe?

Answer (score 2):

[Rig Veda X.88.18](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10088.htm) speaks about many suns.

> कत्यग्नयः कति सूर्यासः कत्युषासः कत्यु सविदापः | नोपस्पिजं वः पितरो
> वदामि पर्छामि वः कवयोविद्मने कम ||
>
> “How many fires are there and ***how many suns***? How many dawns, and how
> many waters? O forefathers, I am not saying something two-faced to
> you: o poets, I am asking you in order to know.

---

Stephanie W. Jamison and Joel P. Brereton in their translation say as follows:

> The last three verses (17–19) seem to provide a simultaneous
> transition from the cosmic and primordial elements in the superimposed
> structures to the present-day everyday—by way of a dialogue between
> **two unnamed participants**.

The rishi is **Mūrdhanvant Āṅgirasa or Vāmadevya**.

He was addressing both **pitris** (forefathers) as well as **other sages** (poets) in the mantra.  So we can infer that the sage Mūrdhanvant Āṅgirasa or Vāmadevya was asking this question, while pondering over the issue.

Like [Nāsadīya Sūkta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasadiya_Sukta) this mantra is posing questions, without answers.

Comment: Please update the response also...

Comment: What shall I update?

Comment: It seems like a question some one is asking another person. What other person replies to it can be updated...

Comment: Then Hymn ends with 19th mantra and it does not give any clue as to who the persons were. @hanugm

Comment: And what about the answer to that question asked by the person, is there any answer given for that question. Please check once...

Comment: You can check for yourself the meaning of [19th mantra here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10088.htm)

Comment: Please update if you know any other... stating as a fact rather than question.....

Comment: Please update if you know any other... stating as a fact rather than question.....

Comment: Let me check up other translations also :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111302/discussion-between-srimannarayana-k-v-and-hanugm).